# TOC hidden in single screen mode

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I routinely use a two-monitor setup with my portable Precision workstation.  When I'm in laptop only mode, my Table of Contents may appear briefly as a shadow on the extreme margin of the screen, then it disappears and I am unable to view it or the catalog windows.  I'm using ArcMap 10.0 and Windows 7.0

Answer (score 2):

I would try deleting the Normal.mxt as described **[here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00v000000014000000)**.

That should restore the factory settings.

As a precaution be sure to follow advice of @blah238 and rename rather than delete the Normal.mxt just "in case it doesn't help and you've customized a lot of stuff".

Comment: You might just rename it so you have a backup in case it doesn't help and you've customized a lot of stuff.